# type hint clone function in python 3.5+

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, type-hinting

Say I have the following classes:

```
class Parent:
    def clone_self(self) -> 'Parent':
        clone = self.__class__()
        # Initialize clone here.
        return clone

    def clone_with_class(self, klass: Type['Parent']) -> 'Parent':
        clone = klass()
        # Initialize clone here.
        return clone

class Child(Parent):
    def child_method(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Is there any way I can get the types to be more specific? I want to be able to say things like:

```
child = Child()
clone = child.clone_self()
clone.child_method()

clone = child.clone_with_class(Child)
clone.child_method()
```

However as written, this will not pass type checks because clone is considered to be of type `Parent` not `Child`.

I tried using `TypeVar`, however this didn't seem to work - at least in PyCharm because it then complained that the type was not callable when I try to call the constructor, possibly because it involves forward references and PyCharm is getting confused.

```
Entity = TypeVar('Entity', bound='Parent')
class Parent:
    def clone_self(self) -> ???:
        clone = self.__class__()
        # initialize clone here
        return clone

    def clone_with_class(self, klass: Type[Entity]) -> Entity:
        clone = klass()
        # initialize clone here
        return clone
```

Is this solution for `clone_with_class` correct? Maybe PyCharm is wrong to complain? Otherwise, what needs to be done to fix the above code?

Should that be `TypeVar('Entity', bound='Parent')` or `TypeVar('Entity', 'Parent')`?

Another solution I have found, although seems somewhat ugly is to insert asserts:

```
child = Child()
parent = Parent()

clone = child.clone_self()
clone.child_method()  # should work

clone = child.clone_with_class(Child)
clone.child_method()  # should work

clone = parent.clone_with_class(Child)
clone.child_method()  # should work

clone2 = parent.clone_self()
clone2.child_method()  # should be an error

clone2 = parent.clone_with_class(Parent)
clone2.child_method()  # should be an error

clone2 = child.clone_with_class(Parent)
clone2.child_method()  # Should be an error
```

Once I have a good understanding of what is considered correct, I can then file bugs against PyCharm if it is incorrectly complaining.

With mypy, I tried, as per suggested answer:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

Entity = TypeVar('Entity', bound='Parent')
class Parent:
    def clone_self(self: Entity) -> Entity:
        clone = type(self)()
        # initialize clone here
        return clone

    def clone_with_class(self, klass: Type[Entity]) -> Entity:
        clone = klass()
        # initialize clone here
        return clone

class Child(Parent):
    def child_method(self) -> None:
        print("Calling child method")

child = Child()
parent = Parent()

clone = child.clone_self()
clone.child_method()  # should work

clone = child.clone_with_class(Child)
clone.child_method()  # should work

clone = parent.clone_with_class(Child)
clone.child_method()  # should work

clone2 = parent.clone_self()
clone2.child_method()  # should be an error

clone2 = parent.clone_with_class(Parent)
clone2.child_method()  # should be an error

clone2 = child.clone_with_class(Parent)
clone2.child_method()  # Should be an error
```

I get the following:

```
$ mypy --strict test.py
test.py:32: error: "Parent" has no attribute "child_method"
test.py:35: error: "Parent" has no attribute "child_method"
test.py:38: error: "Parent" has no attribute "child_method"
```

These errors are expected.

Comment: I added more test cases to test the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if PyCharm currently accepts this or not, but the following code works with mypy:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

Entity = TypeVar('Entity', bound='Parent')
class Parent:
    def clone_self(self: Entity) -> Entity:
        clone = self.__class__()
        # initialize clone here
        return clone

    def clone_with_class(self, klass: Type[Entity]) -> Entity:
        clone = klass()
        # initialize clone here
        return clone

class Child(Parent):
    def child_method(self) -> None:
        print("Calling child method")

child = Child()
clone = child.clone_self()
clone.child_method()

clone = child.clone_with_class(Child)
clone.child_method()
```

Note that I gave `self` a specific type for `clone_self` -- this lets us type the return type more precisely, as you wanted. You can learn more about using generic selfs here: http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self

Your `clone_with_class` method also had a bug in it, which may have confused matters -- you forgot to include the `self` parameter.

Comment: I fixed the ``clone_with_class`` bug, thanks. Was a mistake in the question here, not my test case.

Comment: This gives the error in PyCharm: ``klass is not callable``, for the first line in ``clone_with_class``. I am inclined to think PyCharm is in the wrong.

Comment: According to the documentation you referenced, this is still experimental. So maybe not a case of PyCharm being broken, but this not being implemented yet.

Comment: With mypy in strict mode, I get a warning in the ``clone_self`` function: Returning Any from function with declared return type "Entity`-1". Furthermore mypy in strict mode doesn't like passing ``Parent`` as the parameter to ``clone_with_class``.

Comment: @PenguinBrian -- try using `type(self)()` instead of `self.__class__()` -- currently, `type` has a more precise signature then `obj.__class__`. I'm not able to repro the second issue (though to be fair, I'm using the latest version of mypy cloned from the github repo, so maybe this was a bug that was fixed recently).

Comment: @PenguinBrian -- regarding your 3rd comment, to be fully pedantic, "generic self" is a part of [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#annotating-instance-and-class-methods) and so ought to be recognized by any compliant type checkers (including mypy and PyCharm). However, *mypy* only has experimental support, and PyCharm evidently doesn't yet have support, so it's sort of more accurate to say both checkers are currently broken, since mypy doesn't guarantee full compliance with the spec here and pycharm isn't complaint at all.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. When I said "Furthermore mypy in strict mode doesn't like passing Parent as the parameter to clone_with_class" I realized I was using the ``clone`` variable to store the ``Child`` object, and then trying to reuse the same variable to store the ``Parent`` object. Which - quite correctly - won't work. I didn't read the error message properly - it was quite clear.

Comment: Confirmed: ``type(self)()`` does work better then ``obj.__class__()``